# Node's module.exports and IIFE confusion

Tags: javascript, node.js, iife

I'm been playing around with node and Javascript IIFE and I'm a bit confused with node's **modules.exports** and how IIFE works in Javascript.

```
(function (Calculator) {
    var calculator = function () {
        var currentValue = 0,

            add = function (num) {
                return currentValue += num;
            };

        return {
            current: currentValue,
            add: add
        };
    }();

    module.exports = calculator;
}(module.exports));
```

The above code caused my tests to pass when I used the line **module.exports = calculator;** to export the module.

How come when I use to the parameter **Calculator = calculator** (note the case) causes my tests to all fail?

I thought **Calculator** (the parameter) refers to **module.exports** (the value that gets passed in?

In short:

Calculator = calculator; // Does NOT work

module.exports = calculator; // Does work

Comment: they do == the same value, but not the same name, so re-assigning a value to the local name does nothing to the global.

Comment: The module.exports object is created by the Module system

Comment: @dandavis: That's an answer, not a comment. :-) (But there's no "global" `Calculator`.)

Comment: i usually put English in comments and formatted JS in answers (if a strong need exists ).

Answer (score 2):

I thought this was interesting so i am going to add it. @dandavis is right about them being the same. But i just found out from playing with it you can change the global from the value passed in. Below does put `calculator` as the value for global `module.exports`.
At least it did with this `gulp` stuff i am playing with. I am not a node expert though, so maybe its different in true node server land.

```
(function (Calculator) {
    var calculator = function() {
        var currentValue = 0,

            add = function(num) {
                return currentValue += num;
            };

        return {
            current: currentValue,
            add: add
        };
    }();

    Calculator.exports = calculator;

})(module);
```